# How do I combine multiple RDDs in PySpark (Spark Streaming)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, spark-streaming, rdd

For example - In Spark Streaming I have incoming data of the form -

```
{ 
  "id": xx,
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3,
  "d" : 4,
  "scores"{
     "score1" : "",
     "score2" : "",
     "score3" : ""
  }
}
```

The pipeline for processing it as follows -

```
def func1(row):
   row["score"]["score1"]=row["a"]+row["b"]

def func2(row):
   row["score"]["score2"]=row["b"]+row["c"]

def func3(row):
   row["score"]["score3"]=row["c"]+row["a"]

def publish(iter):
   # publish to some cloud db

# For Each RDD
def process(rdd):
   rdd1 = rdd.map(func1)
   rdd2 = rdd1.map(func2)
   rdd3 = rdd2.map(func3)

   rdd3.foreachPartition(publish)
```

Since all my rdds are being created serially, I understand that there is room for improvement by modifying the process function to -

```
def process(rdd):
   rdd1 = rdd.map(func1)
   rdd2 = rdd.map(func2)
   rdd3 = rdd.map(func3)

   rdd4 = #combine rdd1, rdd2 rdd3

   rdd3.foreachPartition(publish)
```

I have 2 questions -

1. Does the DAG of maps created by this new ordering allow for MIMD
   (Multiple Instruction Multiple Dataset) without explicit
   multithreading?
2. How do I combine multiple RDDs in this case? I am familiar with zip and map to combine two dataframes with same number of rows, but
   how do I combine an RDD of nested jsons?

Example - combining 3 rdds of values of this sort resp. -

```
{ 
  "id": xx,
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3,
  "d" : 4,
  "scores"{
     "score1" : "3",
     "score2" : "",
     "score3" : ""
  }
}

{ 
  "id": xx,
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3,
  "d" : 4,
  "scores"{
     "score1" : "",
     "score2" : "5",
     "score3" : ""
  }
}

{ 
  "id": xx,
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3,
  "d" : 4,
  "scores"{
     "score1" : "",
     "score2" : "",
     "score3" : "7"
  }
}
```

into an rdd of rows of this sort -

```
{ 
  "id": xx,
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3,
  "d" : 4,
  "scores"{
     "score1" : "2",
     "score2" : "5",
     "score3" : "7"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think most probably solution to combine rdd is "do union of rdd" and then perform reduce operation to update score.

Comment: but since it is bad design because all union will accumulate all memory.. so your first approach pipeline process is good in this case.